# RotateAnimation with translationX translationY change in axml

Tags: animation, xamarin, rotation, imageview

I would like to rotate an image.

```
new RotateAnimation(0, 360, Dimension.RelativeToSelf, 0.5f, Dimension.RelativeToSelf, 0.5f)
                {
                    Duration = 1000,
                    FillAfter = false,
                    RepeatCount = 1,
                    RepeatMode = RepeatMode.Restart
                };
```

It works perfetly when I don't have set tranlationX and Y in my axml

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/Icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:translationX="15dp"
            android:translationY="-30dp" />
```

What do I miss?

Comment: you could just add a translation animation and drop the translation from the axml. What exactly is going wrong?

Comment: I need to put my image in a certain position before any animation. Adding translationX and Y bring my imageView in the position I want. But maybe I should use another trick. The center rotation of my animation is placed on the original position and do not care about the translationX and Y from my xaml. So the animation is not a rotation from the center of my image.

Comment: Then I would suggest using one of these https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Views.Animations.TranslateAnimation/ to translate the view before rotating it and removing the translation from the axml

Comment: But I do not want a translate Animation, just A rotate animation.

Comment: Set its duration to 0